# Particles flowing around a masked area

Tags: after-effects

I want Particular in After Effects to animate a flow of particles moving from left to right and bouncing into the perimeter of the mask space around the EXPO logo. Is this possible to create in Particular and if so please tell me how to do it?

[image]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using the built in Foam particle render - it does have basic collision avoidance

https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/simulation-effects.html#foam_effect

You would get a better effect with a physics-based simulator, in 2D using [Newton](https://www.motionboutique.com/newton-physics-simulator-engine-after-effects/), in 3D using Cinema4D or Blender.